# React - imported image to base64

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image

I have question, how convert imported image in react to base64 code?

```
import Image from '../image.png';
```

to

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAF4cAAA7pCAYAAADZ6441AAAACXBIWXMAAB7BAAAewQHDaVRTAAAgAElEQVR4nOzcPXIb2XqA4Q8iqAmBHQBeAZh1CGYO7/UO0CuwJ3N2oR2MV3DGO5gVuArhyaQdwEtAORL/jgt9AVZrRpQoij
```

Comment: are you using webpack to import the image to your react/javascript code?

Comment: Im using create-react-app which contains webpack

Answer (score 0):

Because you use webpack you could use `url-loader` as a loader for your image. It supports importing a file by just returning its content as a data-url like you specified in your question.

[Here is the offical documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) on how to use and integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use canvas for this, I don't know how practical it is

```js
import image from '../image.png';

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 100
canvas.height = 100

const img = new Image()
img.src = image
img.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  let base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);
  console.log(base64Image)
}
```